# Identifying a Select option by using only select name and options value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select name="option[239]" onchange="jsFunction(this)">
    <option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>
    <option value="49">Double Standard</option>
    <option value="50">Single Express</option>
    <option value="51">Single Standard</option>
    <option value="48">Double Express</option>
</select>
<select name="option[240]" onchange="jsFunction(this)">
    <option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>
    <option value="49">Double Standard</option>
    <option value="50">Single Express</option>
    <option value="51">Single Standard</option>
    <option value="48">Double Express</option>
</select>
```

Html

```
function jsFunction(element){
    alert("You changed to " + element.value );
    if (element.value=='50') {
        $('[name="option[240]"]').remove();
    }
}
```

Script

Ok I can get it to remove the entire select option[240] however I don't know how I would remove one of the options from 240 (e.g 49 is removed from option[240] if 50 is selected)

Comment: Please format your code properly next time.

Comment: if `48` is selected what to be removed

Comment: also what is `element` is it the `select` or the `option` element

Comment: What do you mean by "49 is removed from option[240] if 50 is selected"?

Comment: <option value="49">Double Standard</option>

is removed from the select name="option[240]"

Sorry for the unclear names ill edit it now so it's easier to read

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x9RkM/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `element` refers to the select element, you can use it to find the option to be removed.

If you want to remove predefined elements then

```
function jsFunction(element) {
    var $select = $(element);

    if ($select.val() == '50') {
        $select.find('option[value=49]').remove()
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NZ9ZL/)

If you want to remove all the option before the selected one then

```
function jsFunction(element) {
    var $select = $(element);
    var idx = $select.find('option:selected').index();
    $select.find('option').slice(1, idx).remove()
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x9RkM/)

Comment: How would I make it if selected on the 1st select remove the option from the second select?

Comment: if you select from second.. do you want to remove it from first? also then don't you want to remove the selected value?

Comment: Ahh I got it working, one final thing 

function jsFunction(element){
   
  
        if (element.value=='50') {
           alert("You changed to " + element.value ); $('[name="option[240]"]').find('option[value=49]').prop(selected,true);
        
    }
}

Shouldn't this set 49 as selected if you select 50 on the 1st list?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

HTML

```
<select id="test" name="option[240]" onchange="jsFunction(this)">
    <option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>
    <option value="49">Double Standard</option>
    <option value="50">Single Express</option>
    <option value="51">Single Standard</option>
    <option value="48">Double Express</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
$("#test option[value='49']").remove();//it will remove value 49
```

Comment: I know that would work but I need to do it without using id's